# PHP Change Value of Replaced Field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with many fields (id, email, username, etc.) and am wanting to add roughly 26 more fields, call them "a" through "z" for simplicity. They will all have a default value=0 except 4 of them which will initially have values 1 through 4 (e.g., a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=0, f=0, g=0, h=0...). What I want to do is update the value of say, "m" to =1 via a form submission but have a's value now be =0. Everytime the numbers 1-4 are assigned to a particular field the field that was holding that value needs to be switched to 0 so that there is always only a single instance of 1 through 4 assigned.

Have I provided enough information? Good grief, after typing this I'm almost more confused than I was before! I started in on this and was going to pull hair out but I'm already bald.

Comment: If you hear yourself saying: `and am wanting to add roughly 26 more fields, call them "a" through "z" for simplicity`... Then talk to yourself and say : `Don't do that!`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this?

It sounds like a much simpler solution would be to have 4 fields (f1, f2, f3, f4) that can each have a value of A-Z (or blank/space/null).

It will make all future operations MUCH simpler.

Comment: can you hear me laughing right now? holy mackrel do I feel dumb! I need to give this a little while before I delete my question just to make sure the answer isn't really that simple. meanwhile, thank you!

Comment: I'm going to leave this up for a while. It's Friday after all. Everyone deserves a laugh at my expense! Again, thank you for saving me from hours of pointless work.

Comment: Don't delete it, leave it up to save others who have similar issues the pain you almost put yourself through!  :-)  Trust me, you're not the only one to look at a problem one way when there was another simpler way available!